# Error SQL en Laravel 6 (SQLSTATE[42S22])

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Al presentar datos en la vista tengo el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'categories.article_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   `categories` where `categories`.`article_id` = 1 and
>   `categories`.`article_id` is not null)

La llamada la hago de la siguiente forma:

```
{{ $article->category->name }}
```

Desde la GUI en la base de datos se asigna correctamente al campo el valor 1 en el article, que hace referencia en la tabla category al nombre. En mi modelo de article tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
}
```

Y en mi controlador en el index que es donde me falla:

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::latest()->paginate(6);
    return view('blog.index', compact ('articles'));
}
```

Sin embargo en la vista crear me presenta correctamente en select las categorías. ¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Posiblemente tengas declarada al revés la relación `category()` . Tendría mas sentido que sea `belongsTo` en vez de `hasMany`, entonces la llave foránea `category_id` la guardaría el modelo Article.

Comment: Revisa tu tabla en la bd, el error es claro article_id en la tabla categories, a parte de eso debes hacer la relacion belongsTo en tu modelo article

Comment: Solucionado, ha sido un error de copia y pega, era las relaciones, tantas horas de código al final ya no sabes lo que haces. Muchas gracias a los dos